# Use restricted class in an OSGi Bundle

Tags: osgi

For publishing with SSL using the Endpoint I need to access classes under the packages `com.sun.net.httpserver.*`

Using the Eclipse IDE I found a way to use this classes. But exporting the bundles and running them in another equinox OSGi Installation I can't start the bundle throwing the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpsConfigurator
```

Anyone an Idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to have the com.sun.net.httpserver as imported package in your bundle, and inside the container you have to have some bundle, which exports this package.

Comment: Marcel's solution below is indeed the solution to your question, but IMHO this is not the way to go (and it is very unlikely that this is indeed needed). The com.sun.* packages are meant to be private and should be regarded as such. There is probably a more standard solution to your problem. If you elaborate on the problem, you may get an even better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package you're referring to is part of the JDK. You need to expose it, to make it available in OSGi and you have two options:

The first, and in most cases preferred option, is to expose this package through the system bundle. The OSGi framework has a property that you can set to do this:

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=...
```

As its value, you provide it with a comma separated list of packages that you want to expose, on top of the ones that are already exposed by the framework. In your case, at least com.sun.net.httpserver, but there might be more packages that you need. In this case, also make sure that the bundle that uses this package imports this package.

The second option is to use a mechanism used boot delegation. It should only be used as a last resort, as it breaks modularity and if it's not used carefully it might lead to other problems. Again, this is a property that you need to set:

```
org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=*
```

Here, you can provide a comma separated list of packages that should be loaded by the boot class loader. Wildcards are supported (as seen in the example above) but you are encouraged to be as specific as possible, so in your case for example use com.sun.* as the value.

Comment: I am having the same problem under KURA which runs above eclipse Equinox, how can I set the property for the system bundle?