# KURA use of classes under the package: "com.sun.net.httpserver.*" in an OSGI bundle

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, osgi-bundle, kura

I am using KURA on my OSGI developpement, it is running above **Eclipse Equinox**, I want to be able to use the classes of the  "com.sun.net.httpserver.*" in my bundle.

I found out under this link ([Use restricted class in an OSGi Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864569/use-restricted-class-in-an-osgi-bundle)) that I have to specify it through the system bundle using the OSGi framework property:

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=...
```

My problem is I don't know where to set this propertie. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to provide this as an argument (-Dorg.osgi...) when bootstrapping Kura. See the `start.sh` file in `/opt/eclipse/kura/bin`.